# Mongodb aggregation lookup array, is not sorting correctly

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongoose, aggregation-framework, lookup

My MongoDB collection have a field with an array of ObjectId.
This array contains the order of the ObjectIds may appears on the list.
It happens then I trying to use $lookup in aggregation, it's sorting my array by the creation order.

When I use just:

```
$project: {
                list: 1
            }
```

the result is the correct order of the elements:

```
[
  5e9b7dc0500c9a5c3809b0c8,
  5e9b7efad230686164a64bdb,
  5e9b7dfc6244792818f7cdba,
  5e9b7e355a7c843e90a2ed48,
  5e9b7e86efb9111d1c91ea77,
  5e9b7eb26463144eac64cb16
]
```

and when I use lookup the order change:

```
$lookup: { 
        from: 'users',
        localField: 'user',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'list'
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        list: 1
    }
}
```

it's the result

```
[
{_id: 5e9b7dc0500c9a5c3809b0c8 },
{_id: 5e9b7dfc6244792818f7cdba },
{_id: 5e9b7e355a7c843e90a2ed48 },
{_id: 5e9b7e86efb9111d1c91ea77 },
{_id: 5e9b7eb26463144eac64cb16 },
{_id: 5e9b7efad230686164a64bdb }
]
```

Could anybody help me with this?

**edit:**

Using findOne().populate() instead of aggregate() was the easier alternative to me in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$lookup` stage returns the fields in the order they are encountered while querying the `from` collection.  Since the `foreignField` is `_id`, the query executor will likely use the `{_id:1}` index to lookup those documents, which means they will be encounter in the order they appear in that index, i.e. sorted by `_id`.  Since the first bits of an ObjectId are the epoch time that the id was created, that will give them to you in creation order.

If you need the fields to be in a specific order, you will need to either add a field to the looked up documents that you can sort on, or `$unwind` the array before lookup so each lookup returns a single document, and `$group` the results back into an array afterward.

Comment: I got it! Thank you!! Very good and I will use this in more complex solutions!!

However, in this case using findOne().populate() I got the results expecteds. 

Thank you, Joe!!!